# Function that returns the element at a given index

Tags: haskell

How can I implement a function that returns ns element from a list with signature like this? I know usual way with `!!` operator, but here is **Natural** type, so Haskell can't match it to expected **Int**.

```
indexed :: Natural -> [a] -> a
```

Comment: How is `Natural` defined?

Comment: Seems like the kind of thing you would want to pass in the list and n call recursively with tail and n-1 and stop recursing when n is 0, return head of list.  Or something close to that.

Comment: @chepner Non-negative integers.

Comment: That's the definition of natural numbers; what's the definition of your *type* that *represents* them?

Comment: @qxotk yea, seems like it's the only way -_-

Comment: @chepner it's type from Numeric library, dunno what definition it has.

Comment: If you have a function `f` of type `Natural -> Int`, you can simply write `indexed n xs = xs !! (f n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `Natural` is [`Numeric.Natural`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Numeric-Natural.html).
Then you can simply do

```hs
indexed :: Natural -> [a] -> a
indexed 0 (x:_) = x
indexed _ [] = error "OutOfRange"
indexed n (_:xs) = indexed (n-1) xs
```

Comment: Have yet to write a Haskell program, but the answer reads like what I was suggesting :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're referring to the [Numeric.Natural](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.6.5/docs/html/libraries/base-4.12.0.0/Numeric-Natural.html) package

This is a bit of a hack but you could do:

```hs
indexed :: Natural -> [a] -> a
indexed n xs = xs !! (fromInteger (toInteger n))
```

Comment: The conversion might not work since `Natural` is an arbitrary-precision number type. But that is proberbly not a problem though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just this:

```
import  Numeric.Natural

indexed :: Natural -> [a] -> a
indexed nat xs = (xs !! (fromIntegral nat))
```

Trying it under ghci:

```
 λ> 
 λ> z = 0 :: Natural
 λ> :t z
z :: Natural
 λ> z
0
 λ> 
 λ> indexed z [1..3]
1
 λ>
```